# How to update a JSON file from R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have this code:

```
# Preloads ---- 

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
library(svDialogs)
library(downloader)
params <- readLines("params.json")


# end preloads ---- 


# Define server logic 
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    my_params <- reactive({ 
        my_params[4] <- paste0("          \"time_period\":[{\"start_date\":\"", 
                               Sys.Date()-10*365, "\",\"end_date\":\"", 
                               Sys.Date(), "\"}],")
        my_params[5] <- paste0("          \"recipient_search_text\": [\"",
                               as.character(input$the_duns), "\"]")
    })    


    observeEvent(input$get_api, { 

        writeLines(my_params,"params.json")

    })  

    the_data <- reactive({ 
        # the excel workbook to download 
        pages<-list()
        url<-"https://api.usaspending.gov/api/v2/download/awards"
        API_response <- httr::POST(url, body = upload_file("params.json"))
        stop_for_status(API_response)
        json <- content(API_response, "text",encoding = "UTF-8")
        API_data <- fromJSON(json)

        download(API_data[["url"]], dest="dataset.zip", mode="wb") 
        unzip("dataset.zip", exdir = getwd())
        output <- read.table(unz("dataset.zip", "all_contracts_prime_awards_1.csv"),
                             header=T, quote="\"", sep="," ,fill = TRUE)
        output1 <- read.table(unz("dataset.zip", "all_contracts_prime_awards_1.csv"),
                              header=T, quote="\"", sep="," ,fill = TRUE)
```

I am trying to read a pre-existing JSON file in, change some parts of it based on user input, and then write to the JSON file again. Then, I am hoping to use that JSON file to call an API and pull data from a zip file. I need help figuring out why my JSON file is not updating with the number from input$duns. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible to remove the `shiny` components from this question? If you cannot reproduce the problem outside of a `shiny` environment, then there is likely something else going on ... and if you can, then all of the shiny stuff in your question is just a distraction.

Comment: Further, if you're trying to modify an existing json string, it would be helpful to see that string (or a representative equivalence of it).